# Cross platform C++ function in xcode to read files in windows, Linux and MAC OS

Tags: objective-c

I have a C++ Project which reads file. I need to improve the project in a way that it also read files from Mac Os. 
I created a Project in x-code and so far I decided to use `#ifdef TARGET_OS_MAC` and `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` to separate the code for windows and Mac. Now i when i write the code for MAC-Read file using NSString in my main.cpp file, it doesn't work and it gives me error that it does not know the  NSString. I tried creating new project command line and  Foundation type but got the same error.
How to combine these two?

Answer (score 0):

You should include cocoa framework:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```